# configure gdb compiler in netbeans6.8 in linux platform

Tags: c, gdb, netbeans6.8

i have a small problem.can anybody say how we can 
configure gdb compiler in netbeans6.8 in linux platform.

thanks in advance.

Comment: gdb isn't a compiler; can you explain what you're really trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Normally - if you are on Linux and gcc/g++/gdb is installed - then it should work out of the box.

However - if it doesn't work you could try the following:

```
 select `Tools` from the  main menu
 select `Options`
 select `C/C++`
 navigate to `Debugger Command` and enter the path to gdb, e.g. /usr/local/bin/gdb
```

Comment: thanks Vokuhila.

actually my work is done.
i just type a ypm command to install gcc,gdb...
i restart my netbeans ide.
it set all the location of gcc,gdb.. etc.

Thanks for your words.
have a nice day.